# How to install cordova-plugin-printer on ionic 7 with capacitor

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth, capacitor

im making an ionic 7 app that needs to print html via bluetooth, i've tried to install `bluetooth le` and `cordova-plugin-printer` bluetooth le dont appears in the import options and when i use `cordova.plugins.printer.print()` says that printer doesn't exist, ive installed correctly following

```
npm install cordova-plugin-printer
npx cap sync
```

and the same for bluetooth le plugin